# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I am developing Web Application to upload file on Google Drive but it gives exception as :- Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
I don't know What it means?
Please help me...

Comment: @Ohlin can you suggest me solution for this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` and `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Desktop.dll` are two different assemblies and it looks like you're naming them in the wrong way.

Please check on [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Build) side on more information on how to build it.

Comment: But both of these references already present in my Project Solution

Comment: My answer was just a suggestion based upon your limited information. If you need a better answer you need to provide more information, maybe a code snipped or a description of what you've been doing. If you haven't tried it then restart your computer because that fixes a problem remarkable often...

Comment: i did all those things(restart Visual Studio & all that) but still not working... By the way thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when trying to use the calendar api.  I had to uninstall the nuget packages, change the .net version from 4.5 to 4.0 then installed the nuget packages again, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ohlin is correct you have to make sure the correct DLLs are being put in your BIN folder but it didn't solve the problem.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19889747/1561136

Problem occurs when you are authorizing a new client secret for the first time you have to manually click a "Allow" button but this does not work if you're running the SDK in a MVC project.