# Google service object for Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use the Google Calendar API in .NET, specifically I am trying to get a list of events. According to the examples [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list), in different programming languages I need to create a 'service' object and an 'event' object. However, I can't find a clear explanation of what either of these objects is or how to initiate them. Does anyone have an explanation? Or can anyone provide any information or give me a link to where this is explained? It doesn't necessarily have to be in .NET

Here is the example in Java:

```
String pageToken = null;
do {
   events = service.events().list('primary').setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
List<Event> items = events.getItems();
for (Event event : items) {
  System.out.println(event.getSummary());
}
pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();

} while (pageToken != null);
```

Following the advice answered, I am getting the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop, Version=1.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Here is the code, the error occurs on the `credentials = Await...` line

```
Dim credential As UserCredential
Dim clientSecretsPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/client_secret.json")
Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)

Using stream = New System.IO.FileStream(clientSecretsPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None)
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that this sample is for Java. My recommendation is to do the following:

1. Take a look in our VB sample for the Calendar API which is available [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp)
2. You should take a look also in other sample for C#, let's say [Tasks API sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/Tasks.SimpleOAuth2)
3. Start a new project and add a NuGet reference to [Google.Apis.Calednar.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/). Remember that it's prerelease version.
4. Your code should look like the following:

It's based on the 2 samples above, **I didn't compile or test it but it should work.**

```
  UserCredential credential;
  using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("client_secrets.json",
  System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
  {
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
      GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, 
      new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }, 
      "user", CancellationToken.None);
  }

  // Create the service.
  var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = "YOUR APP NAME HERE",
  });     

  var firstCalendar = (await service.CalendarList.List().ExecuteAsync()).Items().FirstOrDefault();
  if (firstCalendar != null)
  {
     // Get all events from the first calendar.
     var calEvents = await service.Events.List(firstCalendar.Id).ExecuteAsync();
     // DO SOMETHING
     var nextPage = calEvents.NextPage;
     while (nextPage != null)
     {
       var listRequest = service.Events.List(firstCalendar.Id);
       // Set the page token for getting the next events.
       listRequest.PageToken = nextPage;
       calEvents = await listRequest.EsecuteAsync();
       // DO SOMETHING
       nextPage = calEvents.NextPage;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, (This is my side project so I didn't get to try this until now). I am getting the error described above in the 'edit'. I found the ''Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll' file on the code.google.com website, but any attempt to attach it is causing errors..

Comment: I attempted downloading the file from here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Current/Generated/Bin/?repo=contrib&r=ad7badbd82e8f4c9179b9902369d2053e2ca8b12 . But that resulted in a different error: `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop, Version=1.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.`

Comment: Please use NuGet to manage your dependencies. Just add a reference to Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/)

Comment: So why are you trying to download - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Current/Generated/Bin/?repo=contrib&r=ad7badbd82e8f4c9179b9902369d2053e2ca8b12? Maybe just start a new project add the required NuGet dependency (that's all...) and then add the code I posted. Let me know if it compiles.

Comment: I was trying to download it because it was giving a `cannot find file` error. The error was giving me a list of file paths where .NET was looking for the dll, so I tried downloading it and sticking it into one of them. I don't know if there is an issue with Nuget, I will try creating a new project later today.

Comment: Ok, finally got it, it looks like .NET was looking in the wrong place for that Dll, I was finally able to located it and place it in the 'bin' folder where .NET was looking for it, everything worked afterwards.

Comment: @peleyal I think the issue here is when Nuget is building the dependencies (for example, when following [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2)) it fails to add the Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll to the references, perhaps this needs updating? I was able to locate it and manually add it to the references in the following folder within the solution, after doing all Nuget installs: \packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16\lib\net40\

Comment: On the other hand, I just tried this on a separate computer using VS 2010 instead of 2012 and *.Desktop was pulled in. Perhaps this is a nuget issue, then?

Comment: Interesting. Microrosft.Bcl.Async documentation says actually the opposite: "This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010". What is exactly the error you get when running it in VS2012? Try to start from scratch targeting the platform you want with the right NuGet references. You should also consider using C# and not VB.NET (Just because I hate VB.NET :))

Answer (score 3):

The problem with GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker is that it tries to launch a new instance of a web browser to go and get authorization where you have to click the "Grant" button.

Obviously if you're running a MVC project under IIS it's just going to get confused when the code tries to execute a web browser!

My solution:

1. Download the .net sample projects: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/checkout?repo=samples
2. Build and run one of the projects relevant to you (Eg Calendar or Drive). Dont forget to include your client_secret.json file downloaded from the cloud console.
3. Run the project and it will open a new browser on your computer where you will have to click the "Grant" button. Do this once and then your MVC code will work because it will not try to open a web browser to grant the permissions.

I'm not aware of any other way to grant this permission to the SDK but it worked for me just great!

Good luck. This took me a good 5 hours to figure out.

Comment: I think you can avoid this if you use a Service Account, see here https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2 . I found that I had to share the Doc with the service account's email, otherwise it would not appear. Apparently there's another way to handle that as well https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same issue running VS2013 (using .net45 for my project):

After fetching the CalendarV3 API via NuGet you just have to **manually add the reference** to:

```
...packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.165\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll
```

to the project (because it is not inserted automatically via the NuGet-Script)!

That's it! Maybe @peleyal is correcting the script somewhen in future ;)

Comment: Genius, this did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and it was due to the app trying to launch the accept screen.
I first tried to get the vb.net example from google and ran that, which I did get to work, and change to my secret info,  ran and got the accept screen.  I then tried my app, and it still did not work.
I noticed that the dll was found here under my project installed from the nuget packages.

...`packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.165\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll`

but was not in the `net45` dir.   So I uninstalled the nuget  packages (have to if changing the .net version) then changed my .net version for my project to 4.0 instead of 4.5, reinstalled the nuget packages, and then it worked!!